# Raw Ethernet project with Stellaris and Raspberry PI

Tags: frame, packet, ethernet, tcpdump

At the moment i'm planning to develop a project with a Stellaris LM3S8962, a Raspberry Pi, and an IP camera.

The communication between the Stellaris and the Raspberry is SPI and between the Stellaris and the camera is Ethernet.

From the Raspberry Pi i send all the packets (previously captured with tcpdump) to the Stellaris. This works fine. Then i send those packets to the camera. The first one is an ARP packet and I get its answer which seems to be correct.

Then i send another packet and a correct answer.. (comparing to the captured packages) but after that i get all packages with the same format and size. I know it's wrong because i compare them with the packets captured with tcpdump.

All of them have this format (same size and almost same data):

```
MAC_DST: b827ebdaf24c
MAC_SRC: 001e58988c8d
TYPE:    0800
```

And after that all this data:

```
4500002800004000ff06f972c0a80014c0a800f800508f1e0735bd500000000050040000d98f0000c0a80014c0a8
```

Do you have any idea what i'm doing wrong?